# Sort by value of multiply field a and field b in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongodb-query

I have `farm` collection that has `apy` and `liquidity`.
I want to get top 10 results by order of value of `apy * liquidity`
I tried like this.

`var data = models.farm.find().sort({ $expr: { $multiply: ["$apy", "$liquidity"] } }).limit(10)`

But it doesn't work well.
How can I get expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another field with the value from apy * liquidity like this

```
  var data = await models.farm.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: {
        apy_times_liquidity : { $multiply: ['$apy', '$liquidity'] }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: { apy_times_liquidity : -1 }
    },
    { $limit: 6 }
  ])
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      return result;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  res.send({ data: data });
```

Comment: What is the result of data?
The console.log is not farms data array.

Comment: What do you get if you output that as an array to the console like this?

models.farm.aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { 
        $addFields: {
            apy_times_liquidity: {
                $multiply: ["$apy", "$liquidity"]
            }
        } 
    },
    { $sort : { apy_times_liquidity : -1 } },
    { $limit : 10 }
]).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});

Comment: Sadly, I tried that as well by googling, but couldn't solve.

Comment: @Li1001 If you try using `await`, do you get the `data` you are looking for?